# ESS to call different installations of R

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I am not sure if this has already been answered here on stack-overflow. I had Emacs-ESS installed on my Unix machine and when ever I start up emacs, particular version of R gets loaded. 
I now have some new R packages that I wanted to test before installing into default R environment. Hence I installed newer version of R in a local directory and have my new packages installed there. Now if I want to call this newer R version that I installed in a local directory, from emacs, how exactly should I be doing it? I want to be able to call either the default R version or the locally installed R-version.

Thanks for all your time and help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ESS can start other versions of R, provided that it knows where on your system they are located.  Pasted below is the relevant section from the [ESS manual](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#iESS_0028S_0029_002d_002dInferior-ESS-processes):

> If you have other versions of R or
>   S-Plus available on the system, ESS is
>   also able to start those versions. How
>   this exactly works depend on which OS
>   you are using, as described in the
>   following paragraphs. The general
>   principle, regardless of OS, is that
>   ESS searches the paths listed in the
>   variable exec-path for R binaries. If
>   ESS cannot find your R binaries, on
>   Unix you can change the unix
>   environment variable PATH, as this
>   variable is used to set exec-path.
>
> R on Unix systems: If you have
>   "R-1.8.1" on your exec-path, it can be
>   started using M-x R-1.8.1. By default,
>   ESS will find versions of R beginning
>   "R-1" or "R-2". If your versions of R
>   are called other names, consider
>   renaming them with a symbolic link or
>   change the variable ess-r-versions. To
>   see which functions have been created
>   for starting different versions of R,
>   type M-x R- and then hit [Tab]. These
>   other versions of R can also be
>   started from the "ESS->Start
>   Process->Other" menu.

Comment: Also `M-x customize-variable` and then `inferior-R-program-name`.

Comment: ESS will also find versions of R beginning with `R-3`, `R-devel` & `R-patched`.

Comment: update: (TIL) other versions of R discovered by ESS during package load are any executable on exec-path whose basename begins with any of "R-1" "R-2" "R-3" "R-4" "R-5" "R-6" "R-7" "R-devel" "R-patched" (though I would recommend Martin's approach to the use case presented in the question).

Answer (score -1):

These methods didn't work for me.  I changed the PATH option to point at the version I wanted, then restarted emacs, and that worked.